# Android Table Layout Color Change

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

I have a 7*7 table which i have filled with numbers from 1 to 49. I want to change the color of the text to green as I touch any number. During ACTION_DOWN event I want to change the color of the text for all the numbers which were touched. Can you help, please.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:columnCount="7"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="7" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="7" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="11" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="13" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="14" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="15" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="17" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="19" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="20" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="21" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="22" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="23" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="25" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="26" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="27" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="28" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="29" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="31" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="32" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="33" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="34" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="35" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="36" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn37"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="37" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="38" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn39"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="39" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="40" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="41" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="42" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="43" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="44" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn45"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="45" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn46"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="46" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn47"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="47" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn48"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="48" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn49"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="49" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create buttun_text.xml in res/color folder and define color when button is pressed.
Add this xml reference in your main layout xml.

**buttun_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ff00ff00"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text"    <!-- add text color xml here -->
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text"  <!-- add text color xml here -->
        android:text="2" />
             .
             .
             .
```